# Background na diagonal

Tags: css, css3

Css :

```
.bio {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 600px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, #fff 50%, #004E95 50%);
}
```

Que gera :

[image: Background]

Porém eu gostaria de trocar `#004E95` por uma imgem, alguém sabe que alterações eu devo fazer para que isso seja possível ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro para ter a imagem vc tem que fazer a imagem, seja no Photoshop, Corel e qq outro software. Ou então vc faz um SVG que é tipo uma imagem vetorial que é interpretada pelo Browser, ai vc coloca a cor que quiser.

Para aplicar no HTML vou te dar duas opções. Uma com Background-image como no seu modelo. E outra com ::after.

**Modelo com `background-image`**

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(http://engiobra.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/trapezio.png);
    background-position: center left 350px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

---

**Modelo com `::after`**

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.bg::after {
    content: url(http://saogeraldo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Produto-saogeraldo-trapezio-black-decortiles.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translate(60%, -27%);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```